# HTML table display JQuery checkbox off-by-one and not preserving data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have some JavaScript code that should display a matrix of checkboxes.  I want to list the column titles across the top, and then put rows where there is a column of checkboxes under each header, plus a left-hand column with row names under a blank header box.  I'm going for the look on this page:

http://codepen.io/marclundgren/pen/hgelI

I wrote a Fiddle that almost works:

https://jsfiddle.net/bv01xvdf/

The first problem is that my table displays the checkboxes on a separate line from the cell with the row name.  I checked my HTML, and it seems correct, but I'm wondering if I'm missing a `<tr>` or a `</tr>` somewhere.  I add the row name cell like this (see the Fiddle for complete code):

```
var chugNames = ["Ropes", "Cooking", "Outdoor Cooking"];
for (x = 0; x < chugNames.length; x++) {
    // Add a row for each name.                             
    target.append("<tr><td>" + chugNames[x] + "</td>");
    for (y = 0; y < chugNames.length; y++) { 
      target.append("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" />");
      checkbox = $('</input>', {
        'type': 'checkbox',
        'data-x': chugNames[x],
        'data-y': chugNames[y],
      });
      target.append(checkbox);
      target.append("</td>");
   }
   target.append("</tr>");
}
```

The other problem is that data-x and data-y return "undefined" when I access them later in my "on" method:

```
   target.on('change', 'input:checkbox', function() {
     var $this = $(this),
       x = $this.data('x'),
       y = $this.data('y'),
       checked = $this.prop('checked');
     alert('checkbox changed chug intersection (' + x + ', ' + y + '): ' + checked);
   });
```

When I check a box, I get "checkbox changed chug intersection (undefined, undefined): true".  It should print something like (Ropes, Cooking), depending on which box was checked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you append with jQuery the tag is automatically closed.

[check the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwn4gddv/)

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  var target = $('#checkboxes');
  var chugNames = ["Ropes", "Cooking", "Outdoor Cooking"];
  var i, x, y, checkbox, html;
  html = "<table class=\"responsive-table-input-matrix\"><thead><tr><th></th>";
  // Table column headers                                                   
  for (i = 0; i < chugNames.length; i++) {
    html += "<th>" + chugNames[i] + "</th>";
  }
  html += "</tr></thead><tbody>";

  for (x = 0; x < chugNames.length; x++) {
    // Add a row for each chug.                             

    html += "<tr><td>" + chugNames[x] + "</td>";

    for (y = 0; y < chugNames.length; y++) {
      html += "<td>";
      checkbox = '<input type=checkbox ';
      checkbox += ' data-x=' + chugNames[x]
      checkbox += ' data-y=' + chugNames[y]
      checkbox += '/>'
      html += checkbox;
      html += "</td>";
    }
    html += "</tr>";
  }
  html += "</tbody></table>";

  target.append(html).width(function() {
    return $(this).find("input:checkbox").outerWidth() * chugNames.length
  });

  target.on('change', 'input:checkbox', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      x = $this.data('x'),
      y = $this.data('y'),
      checked = $this.prop('checked');
    alert('checkbox changed chug intersection (' + x + ', ' + y + '): ' + checked);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed both issues.  One tiny correction: the chugNames[x] and chugNames[y] appends need quotes, since they might be multi-word.  Everything else works great- thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/b43w6ft5/2/).

For the record, you had a few problems, an extra `<th></th>` in the opening string, an extra output of ChugName[x] and you didn't use the `attr()` jQuery function to get the data attributes properly.

Comment: Hm- I tried the Fiddle at b43w6ft5, but I'm still getting the same error.  Am I viewing it incorrectly?

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, I forgot to save :P. Try it with this one: https://jsfiddle.net/b43w6ft5/2/ . I also updated the answer with the new jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you!  That fixed the layout error.  I still don't get the table values, but the answer below this one fixes that. :)  Many thanks again!